# How to Convert Coordinates to QString

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Cascades BB10, I want to convert latitude and longitude from double to QString, I used this code

```
QString lat = QString::number(coordinates.latitude());
QString lon = QString::number(coordinates.longitude());
```

Now when I debug with the following values

```
coordinates.latitude() = 43.481927999999996
coordinates.longitude() = -80.540750000000003
```

I get the following strings:

```
lat = 43.481927999999996
lon = nan
```

The problem is `lon = nan` while I expected a value of `-80.540750000000003`

What causes this behavior?

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't work. Here's another way of doing it that you may want to try: QString lon = QString("%1").arg(coordinates.longitude());

Comment: I tried QString("%1").arg(coordinates.longitude()); doesn't work too, I think that because -80.540750000000003 is "long double" not "double"

Comment: you may try `QString::number(static_cast<double>(coordinates.longitude()))`

Answer (score 0):

Try `QString::number(coordinates.longitude(), 'f', 15)`.